# Why is my img leaving a 1px unfilled space in a table cell?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am writing some HTML to go in a mail to be sent to internal users programatically. They all use Outlook 2016. (Coding for Outlook is horrific, as simple things like CSS backgrounds don't work. As such I'm stuck with coding HTML like it's the 90's.)

The content is kind of a flowchart, and it needs to be visible in the mail client as the users won't bother clicking a link to take them to an external page. As it is Outlook I am doing everything with tables. Basically, everything graphical is a table cell, but I need to add arrowheads. I have done this by coloring the background of the cell and "capping it" with a white on transparent arrowhead cutout.
[image]

I'm pretty much there, except for a really annoying bug where on some, but not all of the arrows, there is a 1px line to the left of the arrowhaed. (The ones in the picture with red arrows pointing to them.)

My arrowhead image is the same width as 2 x my column width, and the code is as follows to make a row with 2 arrowheads (I'm using 36 columns, as the design is based on a 12 column grid, but then I need to be able to split down cells further in order to make the arrows):

```css
body {
  font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 6px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 935px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

th {
  width: 26px;
}

td.shaft {
  background-color: #82d0f5;
  padding: 0px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  height: 24px;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #82d0f5;
  height: 48px;
  border-right: 6px solid white;
  padding: 6px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
td a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
}

td.divider {
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #f7c437;
}
.title {
  font-size: 36px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align:left;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #291f68;
}
.highlight {
  color: #55abe6;
}
img {
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
td.summary {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
  padding-bottom:36px;
  word-break: normal;
}
td.blank {
  background-color: white;
  padding:0;
  height: 24px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td colspan=18>Are just Powerpoint toolbars missing? <br /><a href='http://www.google.com'>Y - Click Here</a></td>
    <td class='blank' colspan=8></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2></td><td class='blank' colspan=8></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row with 2 arrows -->
  <tr>
    <td class='blank' colspan=8></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2>N</td><td class='blank' colspan=8></td>
    <td class='blank' colspan=8></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2>N</td><td class='blank' colspan=8></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='blank' colspan=8></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2><img src='http://www.amstaffportal.com/images/email_resources/arrowhead.png' /></td><td class='blank' colspan=8></td>
    <td class='blank' colspan=8></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2><img src='http://www.amstaffportal.com/images/email_resources/arrowhead.png' /></td><td class='blank' colspan=8></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Row with 2 arrows -->
  <tr>
    <td colspan=36>Did this fix your issue? </td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Row with 3 arrows -->
  <tr>
    <td class='blank' colspan=5></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2></td><td class='blank' colspan=5></td>
    <td class='blank' colspan=5></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2></td><td class='blank' colspan=5></td>
    <td class='blank' colspan=5></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2></td><td class='blank' colspan=5></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='blank' colspan=5></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2><img src='http://www.amstaffportal.com/images/email_resources/arrowhead.png' /></td><td class='blank' colspan=5></td>
    <td class='blank' colspan=5></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2><img src='http://www.amstaffportal.com/images/email_resources/arrowhead.png' /></td><td class='blank' colspan=5></td>
    <td class='blank' colspan=5></td><td class='shaft' colspan=2><img src='http://www.amstaffportal.com/images/email_resources/arrowhead.png' /></td><td class='blank' colspan=5></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- End Row with 3 arrows -->
  <tr>
    <td colspan=12 style='background-color:#70b74b; color:white'>Yes - close the call</td>
    <td colspan=12 style='background-color:#e9531b; color:white'>No - I need more help</td>
    <td colspan=12 style='background-color:#2f7de1; color:white'>This was not relevant <br /> to my issue</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

How do I get rid of the troublesome line on the left?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? It's easier to help if we can reproduce this problem somewhere.

Comment: I can’t in a fiddle - in a browser it works fine. It only manifests in Outlook.

Comment: Can you then create a working code snippet where we can see it working fine. That will surely bring us closer to discovering why that working code snippet isn't working fine in Outlook.

Comment: Please see updated snippet. Sorry for all the th tags - couldn't find a shorthand way of doing it so the code still worked!

Comment: This looks a lot like [Outlook add 1px right to cell image](//stackoverflow.com/q/41735636) except the other side...